# Foreach multi-state control

Tags: php

I'm listing data with Foreach and I'm trying to print it as 1 if all of this data is active and 1 is active, but there is a problem with the code

```
foreach($veri as $data) {

 if($data['status']==1){

   echo 'active';

  } else if($data['status']==2){

   echo 'not active'; 

  }
}
```

Result:

```
1active1active1active2not active
```

trying to do

```
active or not active
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your loop. i think the issue could be from the code before the loop runs

Comment: There is literally no way the PHP code shown produces _"1active1active1active2not active"_. Where do the numbers come from? Can you also please explain clearly what _"print it as 1 if all of this data is active and 1 is active"_ means?

Comment: can you add the code where you declared the array you're looping through

Comment: @Phil I'm holding a json data in the database. There are a lot of data here and they have a situation. If the status of each data is 1 get active. If the status of each data is not 1 I am trying not to be not active.

Comment: @FestusYuma I get the s status of the data that I have saved json in the database.

Comment: @BerkayKara it doesn't seem like the result you're getting iscoming from inside the loop so it would be really helpful if i could see most if not all of the code that runs before the loop begins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to only print *"active"* if **all** entries have `status` equal to `1` and *"not active"* otherwise.

You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-reduce.php) to reduce the array to a single boolean

```php
$allActive = array_reduce($ver1, function($active, $data) {
    return $active && $data['status'] === 1;
}, true);

echo $allActive ? 'active' : 'not active';
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/5Ve9d

---

The above is somewhat inefficient as it will iterate over the entire array, even after it finds a value other than `1`.

This is slightly more verbose but optimally exits early

```php
$allActive = true;
forEach($ver1 as $data) {
    if (!($allActive = $data['status'] === 1)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/UDSpt